# Is there a way in Laravel to use multiple connections simultaneously in a combined manner?

Tags: laravel, database, join, connection

My Laravel configuration files and code are as follows:

config/database:

```
'mysql1' => [
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'url' => env('DATABASE_URL1'),
      'host' => env('DB_HOST_1', 'Example IP1'),
      'port' => env('DB_PORT_1', 'Example Port1'),
      'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_1', 'forge'),
      'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_1', 'forge'),
      'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_1', ''),
      'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_1', ''),
      'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
      'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      'prefix' => '',
      'prefix_indexes' => true,
      'strict' => true,
      'engine' => null,
      'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
      ]) : [],
    ],

'mysql2' => [
   'driver' => 'mysql',
   'url' => env('DATABASE_URL2'),
   'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', 'Example IP2'),
   'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', 'Example Port2'),
   'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge'),
   'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge'),
   'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
   'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_2', ''),
   'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
   'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
   'prefix' => '',
   'prefix_indexes' => true,
   'strict' => true,
   'engine' => null,
   'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
   ]) : [],
  ],
```

env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql1
DB_HOST_1=Example IP1
DB_PORT_1=Example Port1
DB_DATABASE_1=AutomobileAppDB
DB_USERNAME_1=ExampleUser1
DB_PASSWORD_1=ExamplePass1
DB_SOCKET_1=path1

DB_CONNECTION2=mysql2
DB_HOST_2=Example IP2
DB_PORT_2=Example Port2
DB_DATABASE_2=AutomobileAppDB
DB_USERNAME_2=ExampleUser2
DB_PASSWORD_2=ExamplePass2
DB_SOCKET_2=path2
```

Cartable model code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Cartable extends Model
{
  public static function getCombinedData()
  {
    $servers = DB::connection(env('DB_CONNECTION1'))
      ->table(env('DB_DATABASE_1') . '.db_manager_servers')->get();

    $mainconn = $servers[0]->connection_name;
    $maindbname = $servers[0]->database_name;

    $data = collect();
    foreach ($servers as $server) {
      $conn = $server->connection_name;
      $dbname = $server->database_name;

      $sql = 'SELECT ' .
        $conn . '.' . $dbname . '.documents.docyear,' .
        $conn . '.' . $dbname . '.documents.docno,' .
        $mainconn . '.' . $maindbname . '.doctype.name
        FROM ' .
        $conn . '.' . $dbname . '.documents
        JOIN ' .
        $mainconn . '.' . $maindbname . '.doctype
        ON ' .
        $conn . '.' . $dbname . '.documents.doctype_id
        = ' .
        $mainconn . '.' . $maindbname . '.doctype.id';
      
      $sqlcode = DB::select($sql);
      $data = $data->merge($sqlcode);
    }

    dd($data);
    return $data;
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.doctypes ON mysql1.Automobi...' at line 6

These test queries work:

```
   $sql = 'SELECT AutomobileAppDB.documents.docyear,
            AutomobileAppDB.documents.docno,
            From
            AutomobileAppDB.documents
            ';
$data = DB::connection('mysql1')->select($sql );
dd($data );
```

and:

```
$sql = 'SELECT AutomobileAppDB.doctypes.name
      From
      AutomobileAppDB.doctypes
      ';
$data = DB::connection('mysql2')->select($sql );
dd($data );
```

How can I combine data from the two connections using a single query?
I get an error when I enter the connection for each section.

Comment: You cannot. The two database connections don't know anything about the other, and has no connection to each other. You can do joins and unions for databases on the same server, but it would still have to use the same connection.